# Cognos TM1 - how to get username into Excel report

Tags: cognos

I need to have cube with usernames dimension. I need to write to the cells of username that is actually logged in when he opens report.

I have some idea about solution, but I need to get username of logged user into report worksheet.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Worksheet Function:
[TM1User(serverName)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ctm1/v9r4m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.tm1_ref.9.4.1.doc/tm1_ref_id13516wrk_tm1user.html)